# Sqlite create db with multi tables from raw file

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I want to create a DB with 2 tables in Sqlite.
For 1 table it work but 2 not. I have in my raw folder one create_schema.sql file with:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_USA (
    _id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    user varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    pass varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    cod varchar
    );

CREATE INDEX UNIQUE_ENTRY_DATE ON USER_USA (_id);
```

and i have this:

```
   if (mDb == null || !mDb.isOpen()) {

            final File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(MyDbClass.DB_NAME);
            final boolean wasExisting = dbFile.exists();
            if (!wasExisting) {
                // We read the sql to create the DB
                final String createDbStatement;
                try {
                    createDbStatement = ResourceUtils.getRawAsString(mContext, R.raw.create_schema);

                    // If it's not present we create it
                    DatabaseUtils.createDbFromSqlStatements(mContext, MyDbClass.DB_NAME, DB_VERSION, createDbStatement);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG_LOG, "Error creating DB", e);
                    return;
                }
            }

            mDb = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(MyDbClass.DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        }
```

Now if i try to modify the create_schema.sql file like below not work:

```
  CREATE TABLE USER_USA (
        _id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        user varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        pass varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        cod varchar
        );
CREATE TABLE GOOGLE_KEY (
        _id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        regid varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,

        );
CREATE INDEX UNIQUE_ENTRY_DATE ON USER_USA (_id);
CREATE INDEX UNIQUE_ENTRY_DATE ON GOOGLE_KEY (_id);
```

where i'm wrong?

Error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: GOOGLE_KEY (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM GOOGLE_KEY
```

Comment: Any error/exception/issue?

Comment: did you uninstall the application before it after the schema update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an improper ending to a create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE GOOGLE_KEY (
    _id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    regid varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,

    );
```

There is a hanging comma there, so the table won't be constructed.  Look at the ending of your first create table statement, and fix this one to look like that one.

Comment: thanks, now i have this error:  index UNIQUE_ENTRY_DATE already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE INDEX UNIQUE_ENTRY_DATE ON USER_USA (_id)

Comment: If you already ran the script before then the index already exists, that would cause the error.  You can add "IF NOT EXISTS" to the CREATE statement to avoid that.